# Does the html5 "pattern" attribute work in every browser?

Tags: html

Does html5 [pattern attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) work in every browser or not? If doesn't work which technique should I use to work in every browser?

Comment: @MarcB That's worse than dividing by 0!

Comment: @MarcB HTML5 actually includes a "pattern" you can set for input boxes (possibly others as well, just quickly checked), so the author is actually asking about a specific piece of HTML5 functionality.

Comment: @kitsune: yah, but at the time the op's question wasn't specific enough to differentiate between the pattern attribute, or "design pattern".

Comment: @Sonic42: Actually, dividing by 0 factorial is a valid operation.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't. Though you can use JavaScript to get the attribute and validate it that way.

```
if ( ! input.hasOwnProperty('pattern') 
     && ~input.value.search(input.pattern)) {
   // Valid input field for browsers which don't support `pattern` attribute.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meMhB/).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I *think* you can throw any `pattern` at `regexp.test(pattern)` to validate it.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. i was use in my login form like that <input type="text" name="username" maxlength='16' required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,}" /> this pattern doesn't work in every browser. How should i do to work in every browser?