# HTML5 Pattern With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, html, design-patterns

The issue I am having is that I want to create a javascript code that works with my html5 pattern attribute in my form.

The pattern itself is stating that the first letter must be capital and a max of 12 characters. This is what I have so far. Thanks to Juhana, I got a better pattern code that works.

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z]{0,11}$
```

The javascript is supposed to instantly tell on the screen that the person is making an error with their input into the field and specify exactly what is wrong with it. I don't have a code for this at all because I dont even know how to make it work with the pattern rule.

I have been stuck with this for a week now and I cant figure it out.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: let the code speak for itself. what have you tried? where's your code?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do with the pattern. Wouldn't `^[A-Z][A-Za-z]{0,11}$` cover the requirement?

Comment: Juhana that did fix my pattern! I dont know why i added all those other rules to the code... Now the only thing i have a problem with is using javascript to show instantly what exactly is wrong with pattern itself...

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255752/does-the-html5-pattern-attribute-work-in-every-browser

Comment: i saw you experimenting with the fiddle. Did you succeed?

Comment: Lee it does answer most of my question. Christoph, how did you see me messing with it haha, and no i cant figure out how to make it show which rule is being invalidated in the input field instantly

Comment: have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcNLV/20/)

Comment: For some reason when i try to adapt the pattern to my pattern it only allows me to use upper case letters.

Comment: you cant apply the whole regex to the check loop

Comment: now, how far are you with your solution?

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution after messing around a bit with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only opportunity to identify the error in a given string I see at the moment Is the following: You have to break up your regex and loop over the string.

Since your regex is fairly easy, you can start with `^[A-Z]` to check if the first Symbol mathces a letter.

After that you go like this:

```
function check(string){

    var error = false,
        position = -1;

    loop : for(i=1;i<string.length;i++){
        var res = string.substring(i,i+1).match(/[A-Za-z]/);
        if(!res){
             position = i+1;
             error = true;
             break loop;
        }
    }
    return {'error':error,'position':position};
}


var check = check("aasfcd");

if (check.error){
    document.write("Error occured on position: "+check.position);
}else{
    document.write("Your string is okay");
}

​
```

See [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcNLV/1/)