# How do I prevent invalid characters from being entered into a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onkeypress

For example, if I have a form and I don't want the user to enter numbers in it and I validate it with a function containing a regular expression, how do I prevent the invalid character the user entered (in this example, a digit) from showing up in the text form if it fails the regular expression test?

This is the function I tried and the select list I tried it on (in other words, this isn't the whole program). I tried returning false to the onkeypress event handler but what the user enters into the textbox still goes through.

```
function noNumbers(answer) {  //returns false and displays an alert if the answer contains numbers
     if (/[\d]+/.test(answer)) {    // if there are numbers
         window.alert("You can not enter numbers in this field");
         return false;
     }

}

<form action="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <select id="questions" name="questions">
         <option value="no_numbers">What is the name of the city where you were born?</option>
         <option value="no_letters">What is your phone number?</option>
         <option value="no_numbers">What is the name of your favorite pet?</option>
         <option value="no_letters">What is your social security number?</option>
         <option value="no_numbers">What is your mother's maiden name?</option>  
    </select>
    <p><input type="text" name="answer" onkeypress="validateAnswer();" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Err... as you said, by returning `false` in the `keypress` event handler. What did you try? We want to see the code you tried.

Comment: Why do that? Just validate it before you send the data, annoying users with restrictions on input is just, well, annoying.

Comment: It's for a school assignment. That's also why I didn't post the code when I first asked this question. Because people in the class can copy it and claim it as their own. But I guess I have to post some code for people here to see what's wrong.

Comment: You're not checking the key being pressed, you're checking the answer after the new character has been added to the input field. By then it's too late to prevent it.

Comment: How would I check the key being pressed? From what I understand I need to do something involving unicode.

Comment: The handler receives an `event` argument, and the key code is `event.charCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function you are looking for

```
function validateAnswer(src) {
    var questions = document.getElementById("questions");
    var rule = questions.options[questions.selectedIndex].value;
    if(rule=="no_numbers") src.value = src.value.replace(/\d/g, '');
    if(rule=="no_letters") src.value = src.value.replace(/\w/g, '');
}
```

just send the input field reference to the function and set it to `onkeyup` event instead:

```
<input type="text" name="answer" onkeyup="validateAnswer(this);" />
```

you should also hook the `onchange` event of the selectbox to reset the value of the input box. I suggest you also consider the `HTML5 pattern attribute`. See

- [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/754fF/1/)
- [patern attribute support](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html)
- [workaround for unsupported browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255752/does-the-html5-pattern-attribute-work-in-every-browser)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do the thing with returning false and the Unicode (that's what the textbook instructions said to do) but I did something like what you described here and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This validation works great for stripping invalid characters on the fly as you enter them in the relevant field. Example:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  Email:
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onkeyup='res(this, emailaddr);' ; </form>

  <script>
    var phone = "()-+ 0123456789";
    var numb = "0123456789";
    var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ @-'.,";
    var alphanumb = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ @-.'1234567890!?,:;£$%&*()";
    var alphaname = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ,-.1234567890";
    var emailaddr = "0123456789@._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    function res(t, v) {
      var w = "";
      for (i = 0; i < t.value.length; i++) {
        x = t.value.charAt(i);
        if (v.indexOf(x, 0) != -1)
          w += x;
      }
      t.value = w;
    }
  </script>
```

Then you would simply change the second value of the javascript call to the type of data you want entered in the field using the variables that are defined within the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life simpler by adding an extra parameter to your `validateAnswer` function like this:
`<input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" onkeyup="validateAnswer(this);" />`

Then you can define your `validateAnswer` like this:

```
function validateAnswer(elem){
    elem.value = elem.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
}
```

Here an example: http://jsbin.com/iwiduq/1/

Comment: What if I want to replace all `<>{}[]+` characters only?

Answer (score 0):

You get the key being pressed from the event object passed to the handler.

```
input type="text" name="answer" onkeypress="validateAnswer(this, event);" />

function validateAnswer(element, event) {
  if (event.charCode) {
    if (/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode))) {
      window.alert("You can not enter numbers in this field");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Googling for "onkeypress event" finds many examples of this.