# How to allow text and number but not allow special char in this input?

Tags: jquery, css

How to allow text and number but not allow special char in this input ?

in my code , it's will allow only number, i want to apply to allow text too,

How can i do that?

and can i user this function base on javascript ?

http://jsfiddle.net/mhgv0wt0/

```
<form action=# name=f1 id=f1 onsubmit="return false">
<input type=text name=t1 id=t1 value="" size=25 style="width:300px;"
 onkeypress="if(this.value.match(/\D/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"
 onkeyup   ="if(this.value.match(/\D/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"
>
</form>
```

Comment: Define “allow” (should the checks be made when entering characters, or upon submission?), “number” (is −3.14 a number?), and “text” (is “fiancé” text?). When you have exactly defined the problem, you have almost solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a pattern attribute:

```
<input pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$" type="text" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qfz1dhh/)

The above will do in most browsers. But you can fall back to jQuery using

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (!/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qfz1dhh/1/)

Comment: This will only work in [certain browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms).  For older browser support you'll need javascript as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9255770/2414886)

Comment: @SarahBourt be patient :)

Comment: you might want to use the whitespace character (\s)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8qfz1dhh/1/

it's ok , but i want to remove special char when keyup even

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery. Also you might want to use the whitespace character (\s)

```
$('#t1').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhgv0wt0/8/)

Comment: i can not insert special into input too.